# Handling payments in react-native

Tags: react-native, expo, payment-gateway, payment

So I am building an app with react-native (expo) where a user fixes appointment with some other person and to do so, he has pay the other person.

Now how can I handle payments here. What i want is the user makes the payment and the receiver should be the other person but how much i understood the payment gateways, the payment is received by the app owner or in simple words, receiver is a single person.

I also tried deep linking to directly take the user to some UPI app like google pay or paytm but it seems that those apps require some special type of account (merchant account) to make the transaction if we access them using deep links (which is a problem as it is not necessary that every user will have a merchant account).

Comment: Hmm yeah, and I feel that is the best way to go. You can store the user information to whom the money should be forwarded, and write some backend logic to do so? In case of situation where you want direct transactions to receiver, it becomes very difficult to confirm if the receiver has actually received it. Instead you receive the payment and forward it to the right person.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If you know any thing more regarding this, please comment or add as answer.  Also i think deep linking is a good option. How can we do that properly as i already mentioned that it has some restrictions

Comment: The Googlable buzzword you're looking for is `Marketplace payments`. Lots of payment providers have commercial products for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most close answer to my question is to use razorpay routes where we can link multiple accounts with our account and transfer money accordingly.

More details [here](https://dashboard.razorpay.com/app/route/payments)

Answer (score 1):

As I said, it is always better that you have your own payment gateway account, and all the transaction goes through your gateway, meaning you get the money and you build a system which will forward the payment to the receiver. I have worked on 2 such apps:

**1:** Where we have our own razorpay account, and we get the payment first, and then we forward it.

**2:** Where in we were directly having transaction between 2 users, but not through app, instead we display them the account details of the receiver and give them 48hrs time to pay that account. But we had to manually handle this scenario since one cannot know if the user has paid to the said account, since it's not your account.

**3:**  There is one more method where in payment gateway has a webhook which consists of a virtual account number, and every user that lands on your app, you can create a virtual account number for him/her and store the user-virtual account number relationship in your db, whenever there is a payment, you can find out about the user through this virtual account number. Read about this.

The deep link is a good idea, but again, as you mentioned, it will require the end user to be a merchant user(have a merchant account), you can find more details [here](https://setu.co/payments/upi-deeplinks)
Maybe you can ask your users to create a merchant account, which again I am not sure if it's possible, and if it's possible, if it's feasible?

The **best way according to me** is, you handle this through your payment gateway, and instantly forward it to the user who should have received it. Again there are some rules and clause to it(some commission is taken by those payment gateway,etc), check those things out.

Comment: Thanks. So there are ways in the payment gateway to handle such things?? Or do i have to build that from scratch??

Comment: Check my point 3 that I edited just now, that might help you. This is present for razorpay, so you can check their documentation: https://razorpay.com/docs/webhooks/

Comment: That is what i wanted (i think). Thank u so much for this great answer.

Comment: https://razorpay.com/docs/smart-collect/dashboard/create/    This is the exact thing which explains my point 3.

Comment: https://dashboard.razorpay.com/app/route/payments this is what i needed.